# Best Way to Initialize Web Driver

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am currently in the process of developing an automation framework and would like to ask a question. What is the best way to initialize the web driver?

Should it be in a Base Test Class that every test class will inherent from and in the BeforeClass, initialize it. Or maybe the web driver should be a singleton object. Or should I use a JUnit Rule. My desirable is that I want to be able to execute the test suite on multiple browsers via a property file. It does not necessarily have to be running on multiple threads, (i.e. Selenium Grid) but I do want the ability to run in sequence. So for example, if in a property file, I have IE and chrome set to true, it will run the test cases for IE, then chrome. So, I would like to know the best way to facilitate this. It will also be data driven, via Excel files and junit parameterized tests.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you use testNG instead of JUNIT. you can pass parameters to test from a configuration file

Comment: We wanted to use TestNG, but architecture said no since we are already using JUnit. I would prefer TestNG. So, we will probably be using the parametrized features of JUnit 4. Just parse the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

We did something like this with JUnit and Cucumber-JVM. We used a singleton for a WebDriver instance. The specific instance that gets created is based on a system property. To run against multiple browsers, we perform separate runs of the Suite with a different system property for the browser type. We manage that in our build tool.

One advantage of Cucumber-JVM is that it's pretty easy to write hooks that run before or after any test. Without that, you'll want to reset some portion of the WebDriver state before each test.

A while ago, in an unrelated case, I wrote a custom test runner to run tests against multiple database systems by extending ParentRunner and BlockJUnit4ClassRunner. It's easier to just script multiple runs of the same suite in the build tool.

I posted a quick pass at https://github.com/sethkraut/multiwebdriver. I'll also post the code below. It would probably need some polish around preparing and clearing the WebDriver instances, but it should be a good starting point.

This class runs an individual test class after populating a WebDriver field.

```
public class SingleWebDriverTestRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
private final WebDriver webDriver;

public SingleWebDriverTestRunner(Class<?> klass, WebDriver webDriver) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
    this.webDriver = webDriver;
}

// Test Description methods
@Override
protected String getName() {
    return super.getName() + " on " + driverName();
}

private String driverName() {
    return webDriver.getClass().getSimpleName();
}

@Override
protected String testName(FrameworkMethod method) {
    return super.testName(method) + " on " + driverName();
}

@Override
protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
    Object o = super.createTest();

    for (Field f: o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f.getType().isAssignableFrom(WebDriver.class)) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(o, webDriver);
        }
    }

    return o;
}
}
```

And this class iterates over multiple WebDrivers creating instances of the previous class

```
public class MultiWebDriverTestRunner extends ParentRunner<Runner> {
private List<WebDriver> drivers = new ArrayList<WebDriver>(
        Arrays.asList(new FirefoxDriver(), new ChromeDriver())
);

public MultiWebDriverTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
}

@Override
protected Description describeChild(Runner child) {
    return child.getDescription();
}

private List<Runner> children = null;
@Override
protected List<Runner> getChildren() {
    if (children == null) {
        children = getChildrenNew();
    }

    return children;
}

protected List<Runner> getChildrenNew() {
    List<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<Runner>();

    for (WebDriver driver: drivers) {
        try {
            Class<?> javaClass = getTestClass().getJavaClass();
            runners.add(new SingleWebDriverTestRunner(javaClass, driver));
        } catch (InitializationError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return runners;
}

@Override
protected void runChild(Runner child, RunNotifier notifier) {
    child.run(notifier);
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Seth, I would be very interested in seeing an adapted version of this custom runner you wrote. Thanks